# PHP: Undefine variable when calling an object with in a function?

Tags: php, warnings

I get **"Undefine variable"** from the following code.

This is all the code from index.php

```
<?php
include "globals.classes.php";
$anObj = new Globals();
logout();

function logout() {
    echo $anObj->getName(); //Warning: Undefined variable $anObj
    exit();
}
?>
```

I know passing $anObj in the parameter will work,

but is it possible to make it work without passing it through parameter?

I want to call a function this way..

logout();

not this...

logout($anObj);

Comment: Using `logout($anObj);` (besides using classes) is a much more common and recommended way of solving this problem.  So I would recommend getting used to it rather than how can I get round it.

Comment: What _Nigel Ren_ wrote. There are other ways, but it requires you to read the manual thought and then your understanding. One context might be _variable scope_: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php  - Keep in mind that some variables are much more expensive than others: The more broad their scope is, the more they are a dependency of all that scope, regardless in use or not. This is why the point that _Nigel Ren_ commented is that important, it allows you to reduce the scope and therefore the cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because $anObj is out of scope. You need to either make logout() a member of `Globals()` and invoque it as:

```
<?php
include "globals.classes.php";
$anObj = new Globals();
$anObj->logout();

// In your class Global() you'll do something like this
class Globals {
   function getName() {}

   function logout() {
    echo $this->getName();
    exit();
   }
}
?>
```

Another solution could be this:

```
<?php
include "globals.classes.php";
$anObj = new Globals();
echo $anObj->getName();
logout()

function logout() {
    exit();
}
```

In that case you won't need `logout()`. But I guess you might want to do a few more things than just an `exit()`